# Laravel Eager Loading - Unexpected Behavior Difference between Code and Tiner

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading, tinker, laravel-permission

I am working on building a front-end for managing users / roles / permissions with the Spatie > Permissions package in the backend.

A feature I am seeking to implement is selecting a Permission and having this selection then display all Users having the selected permission.

Using `php artisan tinker`, I can use the statement:
`Spatie\Permission\Model\Permission::with("roles.users")->find(59);`, with `59` representing the permission->id in question, and the appropriate results are returned.

My problem is that when I take this code to php and I seek to `dd((Permission::with('roles.users')->find(59));` I receive a **Error
Class name must be a valid object or a string** error.

Removing the nested relationship using `dd((Permission::with('roles')->find(59));` is treated appropriately by Laravel.  However I want access to the *Users* that have the specified permission.

In short, the nested eager loading seems to be failing, dependent entirely on whether the code is in Laravel or Tinker.

I am using php v7.3.25 and Laravel 8.22.1

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try to `Permission::with('roles.users')->find(59)->dd()`
anyway, you have extra opening bracket in your code. so, `dd(Permission::with('roles.users')->find(59));` should work

Comment: Thanks for the shot.  This results in the same error: "Error
Class name must be a valid object or a string".  I agree that it should work... not sure if it's something with Spatie, Php or the newer Laravel.  Dropping the relationship to ```with('roles')``` works - just not chained.  And it still works in Tinker, just not from code.

Comment: it could be an error somewhere in your relationship method, please provide them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Problem solved.  Thanks for those that tried to help - your insistence that it should "just work" led me deeper into the code.

The [Spatie Permissions package](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction) is well done and well researched.  Since I was using it out of the box without further modifications, I assumed that the relationships had been setup correctly, and they were.

The problem is with the default Auth utilized.  Spatie wants to use Auth::web whereas Laravel wants to use Auth::sanctum.

Connecting to the User relationship via "roles" was finding a mismatch in the Auth function I had in place and was throwing a generic error.  So if anyone else finds this as a problem, ensure you have continuity in your Auth checks and you'll be good to go.  Note that this doesn't pose a problem for Tinker, which was why the initial behavior was so perplexing.

Comment: What do you mean by "ensure you have continuity in your Auth checks"?